# Can we format placeholder value as currency?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I hava an aura:component input with placeholder populated by custom currency field. I want to show it as currency but component shows it as number. I need to parse placeholder in future so I can't simple format it as text with currency sign.
Advertised_Price__c is currency custom field

```
<lightning:input type="number" formatter="currency" step="0.01" placeholder="{!appraisal.Advertised_Price__c}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Without actually testing myself, in order to have the placeholder itself appear as a currency, I'd think you'd need to format it before binding it to the placeholder attribute.

Generally, I also think I'd avoid having the actual value set in the `placeholder` attribute itself. I could see this leading to confusion on the part of the user.